# How do I get the ball to curl during free kicks in FIFA 12?

Tags: fifa-12

I watched a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMVXXhAI72U) describing how to curl the ball, but when I practice this it doesn't  curl. I use the PC version with Logitech Controllers.

Can anyone describe appropriately how to curl?

Answer (score 5):

The [FIFA Encyclopedia](http://www.fifaencyclopedia.com) page on [Free Kicks](http://www.fifaencyclopedia.com/fifa-12-free-kicks.php) is a good reference. It lists the methods for a number of different free kick types based on your position on the field, including the Dipping Free Kick and the Driven Curled Free Kick. Like the page says, it is important to use a player with high Curve and Free Kick Accuracy stats.

[FIFA Monster](http://www.fifamonster.com) has a list of the [Top 10 Free Kick Takers in FIFA 12](http://www.fifamonster.com/10-best-free-kick-takers-in-fifa) (e.g. Van Persie, Ronaldo), if you want to practice with the top players.

Answer (score 3):

Use the button on your controller which is normally used for a "finesse" shot, the one which forces the player to go for a placed shot rather than a power shot. On a free kick this does much the same, allowing you to apply curve and accuracy.

I use xbox and I would use RB and the left thumbstick for curve. you need to use the equivalent on your controller

Answer (score 0):

this works between 30-40 yards (xbox 360), line the payer on the end of the walls head with the near post, and use 2 bars of power to strike a perfect shot, if you want curl, hold the right thubstick diagonal to what side you want to curl it, it will work 7/10 times.

Answer (score 0):

To curl the ball,you must first press b and then whole the left stick to left if the player is righty and the camera should be in proper place that's how I do it :3

Answer (score -2):

To curl the ball in fifa 12 ps2 first lock the camera and whille powering ur shot tern ther way you want to curve the ball.thats how i do it.

Comment: Why would you answer with PS2 specifications, when the question refers to the PC?